# Dask DataFrame not starting the task with scheduler='processes'

Tags: multiprocessing, pandas-groupby, dask, dask-distributed

I'm trying to apply a custom function with `groupby apply` and `map_partitions`.

If I run the script, in a Spyder project, with `compute(scheduler='processes')` the task doesn't start (progress bar frozen at 0%)

```
ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=64)
d_df = ddf.map_partitions(lambda part: part.groupby().apply(module.custom_func))\
.compute(scheduler='processes')
```

Here's what I get with KeyboardInterrupt

```
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dask\base.py", line 166, in compute
    (result,) = compute(self, traverse=False, **kwargs)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dask\base.py", line 444, in compute
    results = schedule(dsk, keys, **kwargs)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dask\multiprocessing.py", line 218, in get
    **kwargs

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dask\local.py", line 475, in get_async
    key, res_info, failed = queue_get(queue)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dask\local.py", line 125, in queue_get
    return q.get(block=True, timeout=0.1)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\queue.py", line 179, in get
    self.not_empty.wait(remaining)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 300, in wait
    gotit = waiter.acquire(True, timeout)
```

Strangely enough, If I run it by line or line selection it works.

Many thanks.

Comment: I wonder if you are getting an error and spyder is hiding something from you ?  Perhaps try running in an ipython shell or notebook ?

Comment: I tried on a notebook and it runs, the speed up is the same. I suspect Dask is not the problem as I tried with `multiprocessing Pool` and `map` and got essentially the same issue whereas with `joblib Parallel delayed` it works ok. Thanks

Comment: Seems like dask and spyder have had issues in the past: https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/12465